# как передать имя товара в popup окно с помощью нативного js?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно чтобы в popup падало описание соответствующего при нажатии кнопки товара. Всю голову уже сломал. Реально ли это вообще на чистом js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Exercise</title>
        <style>
            body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .product_wrap{
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        justify-items: center;
    }
    .product_item {
        display: grid;
        justify-items: center;
        grid-row-gap: 10px;
    }
    .prod_img_1 {
        height: 150px;
        display: grid;
    }
    .product_price {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .btn_buy {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
        background: rgb(235,63,109);
        color: rgb(252, 240, 240);
        border-radius: 20px;
        width: 110px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    .btn_buy:hover {
        background: rgb(253, 25, 86);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .popup {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.356);
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .popup__open {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .popup__content {
        background-color: white;
        padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    .popup__title {
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }
    .popup__title__name{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: max-content minmax(auto, auto);
    }
    .popup__close {
        display: grid;
        justify-items: end;
    }
    .input {
        grid-auto-flow: row;
        display: grid;
    }
    .btn__form {
        display: grid;
        justify-items: end;
    }
    .btn-sub {
        width: 140px;
    }
    .no__scroll {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="product_wrap">
            <div class="product_item">
                <div class="product_img">
                    <img src="/img/product.jpg" alt="Изображение товара" class="prod_img_1">
                </div>
                <div class="product_name" id="product1_name"></div>
                <div class="product_price" id="product1_price"></div>
                <div class="buy">
                    <button class="btn_buy" id="btn_buy" data-art="product1">Купить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_item">
                <div class="product_img">
                    <img src="/img/product.jpg" alt="Изображение товара" class="prod_img_1">
                </div>
                <div class="product_name" id="product2_name"></div>
                <div class="product_price" id="product2_price"></div>
                <div class="buy">
                    <button class="btn_buy" id="btn_buy" data-art="product2">Купить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_item">
                <div class="product_img">
                    <img src="/img/product.jpg" alt="Изображение товара" class="prod_img_1">
                </div>
                <div class="product_name" id="product3_name"></div>
                <div class="product_price" id="product3_price"></div>
                <div class="buy">
                    <button class="btn_buy" id="btn_buy" data-art="product3">Купить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_item">
                <div class="product_img">
                    <img src="/img/product.jpg" alt="Изображение товара" class="prod_img_1">
                </div>
                <div class="product_name" id="product4_name"></div>
                <div class="product_price" id="product4_price"></div>
                <div class="buy">
                    <button class="btn_buy" id="btn_buy" data-art="product4">Купить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup" id="popup">
            <div class="popup__content">
                <div class="popup__title">
                    <div class="popup__title__name">
                        <div class="popup__title__teleicon">
                            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="popup__title__text">
                            Заказать обратный звонок
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    <div class="popup__close">
                        <button class="btn_close_popup" onclick="popup_close()"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form class="call">
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше Имя">
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Телефон*" required>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup_product_description" id="popup_product_description"></div>
                    <div class="popup_product_price" id="popup_product_price"></div>
                    <div class="btn__form">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-sub">Жду звонка</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>   
        </div>
    
    
        <script>
            let products =  {
                "product1" : {
                name : "Парикмахерское кресло<br>«Норм» гидравлическое",
                price : '9 900',
                },
                "product2" : {
                name : "Парикмахерское кресло<br>«Норм» гидравлическое",
                price : '9 900',
                },
                "product3" : {
                name : "Парикмахерское кресло<br>«Норм» гидравлическое",
                price : '9 900',
                },
                "product4" : {
                name : "Парикмахерское кресло<br>«Норм» гидравлическое",
                price : '9 900',
                },
            }
            
            document.getElementById('product1_name').innerHTML = products.product1.name;
            document.getElementById('product1_price').innerHTML = products.product1.price + ' &#8381';
            document.getElementById('product2_name').innerHTML = products.product2.name;
            document.getElementById('product2_price').innerHTML = products.product2.price + ' &#8381';
            document.getElementById('product3_name').innerHTML = products.product3.name;
            document.getElementById('product3_price').innerHTML = products.product3.price + ' &#8381';
            document.getElementById('product4_name').innerHTML = products.product4.name;
            document.getElementById('product4_price').innerHTML = products.product4.price + ' &#8381';
    
    
            const paddingOffset = window.innerWidth - document.body.offsetWidth + 'px';
            const btn_buy = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_buy');
            
            for (i=0; i < btn_buy.length; i++) {
                btn_buy[i].onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementById('popup').classList.add('popup__open');
                    document.body.style = 'overflow: hidden';
                    document.body.style.paddingRight = paddingOffset;
                    document.getElementById('popup').addEventListener("click", function(e){
                        if (!e.target.closest ('.popup__content')){
                        document.getElementById('popup').classList.remove('popup__open');
                        document.body.style.removeProperty('overflow');
                        document.body.style.paddingRight = 0;
                    }
                })
                }
            }
            
            function popup_close() {
            document.getElementById('popup').classList.remove('popup__open');
            document.body.style.removeProperty('overflow');
            document.body.style.paddingRight = 0;
            }
    
    
        </script>
        
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d233126250.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Реально ли это вообще на чистом js?
> Конечно :)

Вы это почти сделали :)
Надо только
btn_buy[i].onclick = function() {
поменять на
btn_buy[i].onclick = function(event) {

У параметра event есть свойство target, которое как раз указывает на элемент, на котором сработало событие.

Дальше используйте data атрибуты в элементе button.
Как это делать написано тут:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Вот тут много всего интересного.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

P.S. Вы зачем то всем буттонам поставили одинаковый id - что не допустимо.

Comment: Если вас не затруднит - хотя бы чуть подробнее... Тупняк словил конкретный) плюс мне это в новинку(. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы посмотрели ссылки, которые я дал ?
Там вроде бы все подробно описано.

Вот еще одна про event.target
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: Спасибо! Нужно было, видимо, просто поспать))

Answer (score 0):

С помощью таргетов действительно не так уж сложно было сделать:

```
for (i=0; i < btn_buy.length; i++) {
                btn_buy[i].onclick = function(event) {
                    if(event.target.getAttribute("data-art") == 'product1'){
                        popup_product_description.innerHTML = products.product1.name;
                    };
                    if(event.target.getAttribute("data-art") == 'product2'){
                        popup_product_description.innerHTML = products.product2.name;
                    };
                    if(event.target.getAttribute("data-art") == 'product3'){
                        popup_product_description.innerHTML = products.product3.name;
                    };
                    if(event.target.getAttribute("data-art") == 'product4'){
                        popup_product_description.innerHTML = products.product4.name;
                    };
                    document.getElementById('popup').classList.add('popup__open');
                    document.body.style = 'overflow: hidden';
                    document.body.style.paddingRight = paddingOffset;
                    document.getElementById('popup').addEventListener("click", function(e){
                        if (!e.target.closest ('.popup__content')){
                            document.getElementById('popup').classList.remove('popup__open');
                            document.body.style.removeProperty('overflow');
                            document.body.style.paddingRight = 0;
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

Comment: это ответ или дополнение к вопросу? если ответ, то сделайте его пожалуйста, чуть более развёрнутым. а если дополнение к вопросу, то удалите его, пожалуйста, и внесите исправление в вопрос.